# Mystery degree of freedom in VAR coefficient stderr

Tags: matlab, time-series

I've been testing the vector autoregressive coefficient estimation vgxvarx in Matlab's Econometrics toolbox.  Once the coefficients are determined, vgxdisp gives you the choice of showing the standard errors estimated according to maximum likelihood or minimum bias.  The only difference between the two is normalization by number of observations versus degrees of freedom, respectively.  Since both are constant, you should be able to verify the 2 sets of standard errors by converting from one to the other.  Just unnormalize by one constant and renormalize by the other.

I tried this and found that the minimum bias estimate of standard error seems to be off by one in the degrees of freedom.  In the script below, I use vgxvarx to calculate VAR model coefficients and then request maximum likelihood and minimum bias estimates of their standard errors from vgxdisp (DoFAdj=false and true, respectively).  To validate the two, I then convert the standard errors from ML to min bias by unnormalizing by the number of observations (nPoints) and renormalizing by degrees of freedom LESS ONE (found by trial and error).  These scalings have to be square-rooted because they apply to variance and we're comparing standard errors.

I'm wondering if anyone can point out whether I am missing something basic that explains this mystery degree of freedom?

I've originally posted this to [usenet](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/xpFCR6GKMIU).  Here is a modification of the original code that natively sets the data so that it doesn't need to be obtained from http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~econ472/eggs.txt.

```
clear variables
fnameDiary = [mfilename '.out.txt'];
if logical(exist(fnameDiary,'file'))
   diary off
   delete(fnameDiary)
end % if
diary(fnameDiary) % Also turns on diary

CovarType='full' % 'full'
nMaxLag=3
clf

tbChicEgg=table([
   1930 1931 1932 1933 1934 1935 1936 1937 1938 1939 1940 1941 ...
   1942 1943 1944 1945 1946 1947 1948 1949 1950 1951 1952 1953 ...
   1954 1955 1956 1957 1958 1959 1960 1961 1962 1963 1964 1965 ...
   1966 1967 1968 1969 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 ...
   1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 ...
   1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 ...
   2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 ...
   ]',[
   468491 449743 436815 444523 433937 389958 403446 423921 ...
   389624 418591 438288 422841 476935 542047 582197 516497 ...
   523227 467217 499644 430876 456549 430988 426555 398156 ...
   396776 390708 383690 391363 374281 387002 369484 366082 ...
   377392 375575 382262 394118 393019 428746 425158 422096 ...
   433280 421763 404191 408769 394101 379754 378361 386518 ...
   396933 400585 392110 384838 378609 364584 374000 370000 ...
   373000 380000 356000 356000 353000 363000 371000 380000 ...
   386000 388000 393000 410000 425000 437000 437000 444000 ...
   444000 450000 454000 453000 453000 ...
   ]',[
   3581 3532 3327 3255 3156 3081 3166 3443 3424 3561 3640 3840 ...
   4456 5000 5366 5154 5130 5077 5032 5148 5404 5322 5323 5307 ...
   5402 5407 5500 5442 5442 5542 5339 5358 5403 5345 5435 5474 ...
   5540 5836 5777 5629 5704 5806 5742 5502 5461 5382 5377 5408 ...
   5608 5777 5825 5625 5800 5656 5683 5700 5758 5867 5808 5600 ...
   5675 5750 5892 5992 6158 6233 6367 6458 6650 6908 7058 7175 ...
   7275 7292 7425 7500 7575 ...
   ]', ...
   'VariableNames', {'year' 'chic' 'egg'} ...
);
seriesNames={'chic','egg'};
varChicEgg = vgxset( 'Series', seriesNames, 'n',2 );

chicEgg = table2array(tbChicEgg(:,seriesNames));
dChicEgg = diff(chicEgg);
dChicEgg = bsxfun( @minus, dChicEgg, mean(dChicEgg) ); % Make 0-mean
dChicEgg0 = dChicEgg(1:nMaxLag,:); % Presample-data
dChicEgg = dChicEgg(1+nMaxLag:end,:);
nPoints = length(dChicEgg)
yrs = table2array(tbChicEgg(1+nMaxLag:end,'year'));
yrs = yrs(1:nPoints);

subplot(3,1,1);
plotyy( yrs,dChicEgg(:,1) , yrs,dChicEgg(:,2) );

for DoFAdj = [false true]
   % DoFAdj=1 means std err normalizes by df rather than n, where
   % n=number of observations and df is n less the number of
   % parameters estimated (from vgxdisp or vgxcount's NumParam)

   [est.spec est.stdErr est.LLF est.W] = vgxvarx( ...
      vgxset( varChicEgg, 'nAR',nMaxLag ), ...
      dChicEgg, NaN, dChicEgg0, ...
      'StdErrType', 'all', ...
      'CovarType', CovarType ...
   );

   fprintf('-------------------------\nDoFAdj=%g\n',DoFAdj);

   subplot(3,1,2+DoFAdj)
   plotyy(yrs,est.W(:,1),yrs,est.W(:,2))

   vgxdisp(est.spec,est.stdErr,'DoFAdj',DoFAdj);

end

fprintf('\nConvert ML stderr (DoFAdj=false) to min bias (DoFAdj=true):\n');
fprintf('Number of parameters: ')
[~,NumParam]=vgxcount(est.spec)
degreeFree = nPoints - NumParam
fprintf('\n');

stderr_ML_2_minBias=[
      0.148195
       21.1939
    0.00104974
      0.150127
      0.160034
       22.2911
     0.0011336
      0.157899
      0.147694
       20.9146
    0.00104619
      0.148148
   6.43245e+07
        381484
       3227.54
] ...
   * sqrt( nPoints / ( degreeFree - 1 ) );
for iParam = 1:length(stderr_ML_2_minBias)
   disp(stderr_ML_2_minBias(iParam));
end

%--------------------------------------------------
diary off
% error('Stopping before return.');
return
```